# Problema con mi método para exportar la información de un listView1 a un excel

Tags: c#

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]tengo un pequeño problema, les comento me marca error en el if en los parámetros  pBar y  grd aquí les dejo el código:

```
 private void saveExcel(string pBar, string grd)
    {

        SaveFileDialog fichero = new SaveFileDialog();
        fichero.Filter = "Excel (*.xls)|*.xls";

        if (pBar != null)
        {
            pBar.Maximum = grd.RowCount;
            pBar.Value = 0;
            if (!pBar.Visible) pBar.Visible = true;
        }
        if (fichero.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application aplicacion;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook libros_trabajo;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet hoja_trabajo;
            aplicacion = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            libros_trabajo = aplicacion.Workbooks.Add();
            hoja_trabajo =
                (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)libros_trabajo.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            //Recorremos el DataGridView rellenando la hoja de trabajo
            for (int i = 0; i < grd.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < grd.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    hoja_trabajo.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = grd.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                }
                pBar.Value += 1;
            }
            libros_trabajo.SaveAs(fichero.FileName,
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal);
            libros_trabajo.Close(true);
            aplicacion.Quit();
        }

        if (pBar != null)
        {
            pBar.Value = 0;
            pBar.Visible = false;
            MessageBox.Show("DATOS EXPORTADOS CORRECTAMENTE");

        }


    }
```

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: por favor aclara los errores que estas recibiendo...

Answer (score 0):

Segun la firma de tu método, `pBar`y `grd` son de tipo `string`. Lógicamente, `string` no tiene propiedades como `Maximum`, `RowCount` o `Value`.

Imagino que `grd` será un `DataGridView` y `pBar` un `ProgressBar`. Pon esos tipos en la firma de tu método `saveExcel` en lugar de `string`:

```
private void saveExcel(ProgressBar pBar, DataGridView grd)
{
     //tu código 
}
```